# Need Formula for Google Sheets

Tags: google-finance, google-finance-api

need some help with google sheets

1. Let's say I have a stock ticker in cell A1, let's say ACN/ NYSE:ACN
2. Let's assume I have a random price - 370.46/370 in cell B1
3. I want cell c1 to use the info in cell A1 and B1, and pull the **date** on which the stock hit that price

I want to be able to edit cell b1 with various prices and I want a formula that's able to pull up the date on which it hit that price

haven't been able to find a formula to do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.